# How do I move the craft, a manually drawn object from arcade library?

Tags: 2d, python

I'm trying to move a spacecraft across the screen. The craft is drawn with this function

```
 def loadKraft(x, y):
    arcade.draw_line(x, y + 15, x - 7, y - 7,   arcade.color.RED, 1)
    arcade.draw_line(x, y + 15, x + 7, y - 7, arcade.color.RED, 1)
    arcade.draw_line(x - 7, y - 7, x, y - 3, arcade.color.RED, 1)
    arcade.draw_line(x + 7, y - 7, x, y - 3, arcade.color.RED, 1)
```

I'd like to be able to rotate it using the arrow keys and use the up arrow key to accelerate it 'forwards'. I've tried finding a tutorial or something, but I've been unable to find anything that addresses this type of movement with the arcade library, or allows for manually drawing a sprite with the draw functions.

Comment: Presumably you tried passing different values to this function as the x and y parameters?

Comment: @DMGregory yeah

Comment: ...and how did you do so, and what were the results when you did, and how did they differ from what you want?